# How do I create a new instance of class using values from an existing class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instances

I am trying to understand how to create a new instance of a class from within an existing class in Ruby. I found one example, on Stack Overflow, but it isn't clear how the values from the existing class get passed to the new instance. (If I am using the terminology right).

In the example below, I have two classes, *RaceCar* and *RaceDriver*. When initialized **RaceDriver** sets the *name*, *experience=0*, *winnings=0* and makes sure there is no car assigned yet.

When initialized **RaceCar** sets the *number of the car*, the *type*, *damage=0*, *racing_status :ready*, and sets the *driver*.

What I want to do is create a method in the **RaceDriver**, **set_driverscar**, that creates a car for the driver, creating *RaceCar.new* but setting the *driver* to the *name* of the **RaceDriver**. It does not matter if it is in initialization or not, I am just trying to figure out.

How would I do this like in the example below?

I have been beating my head on this for a bit, and I must be missing something obvious but I just cannot figure it out OR find a good example that explains how to do this?

Can you help me with an answer so I can learn what I am missing here?

```
class RaceDriver

  attr_accessor :name, :experience, :winnings, :car

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    set_name(attrs [:name])
    @experience = 0
    @winnings = 0
    @car = nil
  end

  private

  def set_name(obj)
    obj == nil ? no_name : @name = :name
  end

  def no_name
    raise 'There is no name for this driver'
  end

end

class RaceCar

  attr_accessor :racing_number, :type, :damage, :racing_status, :driver

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    @racing_number = generate_number
    @type = "stock"
    @damage = 0
    @racing_status = :ready
    set_driver(attrs[:driver])
  end

  def disable
    @racing_status = :disabled
  end

  private

  def generate_number
    rand(20..99)
  end

  def set_driver(obj)
    obj == nil ? no_driver : @driver = obj
  end

  def no_driver
    raise "A car has to have a driver to compete!"
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you not use `@car = Car.new { driver: self}`  in the `RaceDriver#initialize`?

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I was continually failing my tests with that approach but I realized it was because I was putting the method in the private methods so it was not working with the other class.  Setting the attribute to self was not working because I was overlooking the obvious, it was in private. Moving the method up and using self worked. Thanks.

Comment: You said you wanted to set the instance variable `@driver` for the new instance of `RaceCar` to the name of the driver that creates the instance. @Wand shows you how to set it equal to the `RaceDriver` instance, rather than the name. By saving the instance in `@driver` you gain access to the instance's instance variables (whose values may change later), and also to `RaceDriver`'s public instance methods.